# pass the tablename to getData.php in flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, phpmyadmin

I am making a flutter application using MySQL. In the home page I have a listview as shown below. The database has unique tables for each item in the list view.

What I want is that when I am calling http.get to get all the data from a particular table as per the query mentioned in getData.php, there must also be a procedure to send that table name to that php file so that the query should be completed.

This is getData.php:

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$Table = $_POST['Tablename'];
$query = "select * from ".$Table;
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

and here is the code which I have written to fetch the data. What can I write to send the tablename to getData.php:

```
  Future<List> getQue() async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: Please take a moment to familiarise yourself with the code formatting tool in Stack Overflow, so that when you want to ask another question, you can format your code appropriately. The simplest way to use it is to paste your code, select your code, and click the code formatting icon.

Comment: Whilst you might think this is a good idea posting a tablename, feels like it's going to be open to lots of hacking attacks also select * from table - I guess you can only use that on certain tables? i.e not the ones that are too large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `post` instead of `get` for your http call;

```
Future getQue() async {
  var response = await http.post(url, body:{'Tablename': your-table-name});
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```